# How to remove folder by its prefix on centos

Tags: centos, rm

I have the following folder:

```
/home/web/aku
/home/web/kamu
/home/web/anu
/home/web/dia
/home/web/asik
```

and I want to remove all folders under /home/web/ starting with an "a", so these following folders should be removed using one command:

```
/home/web/aku
/home/web/anu
/home/web/asik
```

I have tried using these following commands that didn't work:
    `rm -rf /home/web/a*` = failed, argument too long
    `rm -f /home/web/a*` = failed, argument too long

Comment: find /home/web/ -name 'a*' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f

Comment: find /home/web/ -name 'a*' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f
rm: cannot remove `/home/web/awewe': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove `/home/web/asdsf': Is a directory

Comment: find /home/web/a* -name '\*.\*' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f
and then later do:
rm -rf /home/web/a*